# Given $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, how many ways to create a subset of size $k$ with at least one odd integer?

Tags: combinatorics

We have a set of numbers $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots,n\}$, $n$ is odd, we have to make another set of $k$ numbers which has at least one odd number.

Going about two ways, make all sets of $k$, $n\mathbin{C}k$ then subtract all not containing odd $\frac{n-1}2\mathbin{C}k$.

A second way, select one odd $\frac{n+1}{2\mathbin{C}1}$ and then selecting the rest.

I'm stuck in a loop figuring what's wrong with the latter method.
BTW reference question $n=25, k=5$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second method double counts some combinations.

For example if you choose $1$ first then a possibility is $\{1,2,3,4,25\}$, while if you chose $3$ first then a possibility is $\{3,1,2,4,25\}$.  Although these are the same, your second method counts them at least twice